# Why is syscall __NR_lchown added to register after operation?

Tags: assembly, system-calls

I noticed in GDB that after I call a __NR_write operation then right after that the __NR_lchown syscall number (16) is being passed to the rax register. The code I got is:

```
.data

BemVindo: .ascii "Seja bem vindo!\n"
Digite: .ascii "Digite alguma coisa\n"

_start:

    mov $4, %rax
    mov $1, %rbx
    mov $BemVindo, %rcx
    mov $16, %rdx
    int $0x80

    mov $4, %rax # had to add this line because I was assuming that value 4 was still there in the register
    mov $Digite, %rcx
    mov $20, %rdx
    int $0x80
```

According to my `unistd.h`:

```
#define __NR_write 4
#define __NR_lchown 16
```

So, since I'm on linux I assume this lchown must have something to do with the command chown right? Anyway, the question is, why is value 16 is being loaded right after I call the operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System calls on Linux follow their own "calling convention" just like C functions. The `int $0x80` system call interface your code is using follows the 32-bit x86 system call convention. Notably in this convention the return value of the system call is returned in EAX. The return value of the `write` system call is the number of bytes written to the file, so unsurprisingly EAX is changed to length of string you're writing.  I believe all other registers are preserved.

Note that in 64-bit code you should be using the 64-bit x86 system call interface instead of the 32-bit one.  The 32-bit interface only uses 32-bit registers, so your program will fail if the strings you're trying to display aren't in the first 4GB of memory.  The 64-bit interface has different system call numbers than the 32-bit interface, uses different registers to pass arguments and uses the SYSCALL instruction instead of INT.